# Formatting DOI field from bbl file

Tags: doi, bbl

How to avoid https prefix?
From bbl file, DOI field prints out like this:

> `https://doi.org/10.7551/mitpress/7503.003.0009`

while the publisher requires it to be like this:

> `doi: 10.7551/mitpress/7503.003.0009`

My `.bbl` file goes like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{ando_zhang}
Ando, R.K., Zhang, T.: Learning on graph with laplacian regularization.
\newblock In: Advances in neural information processing systems, pp. 25--32
  (2007).
\newblock \doi{10.7551/mitpress/7503.003.0009}
```

I am using Overleaf. Any hint appreciated.

Comment: You'd probably want to (re-)define `\doi` as `\renewcommand*{\doi}{doi: \url}` or `\renewcommand*{\doi}[1]{doi: \href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}` (written just from memory and untested for lack of a proper MWE, the definitions assume something like the `url` or `hyperref` package). I can only offer a good and tested solution if I get to see a short example document that shows more than just the `.bbl` file.

Comment: @moewe  this just works, I would accept it as an answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `.bbl` file uses a macro called `\doi` it should be possible to get the output you want by redefining that macro. Depending on the packages you load you may want to try

```
\renewcommand*{\doi}{doi: \url}
```

or

```
\renewcommand*{\doi}[1]{doi: \href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```